# react-redux reselect within an object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, reselect

My initial state was :

```
initialState = fromJS({
name : '',
dataList : {
text : '',
}
});
```

I have been trying to access the **text** inside the dataList using createSelectors.

These are the codes that I have tried.

```
const data = state => state.get('addData', initialState);

const x = () =>
  createSelector(data , (prop, dataList ) => ({
    ...prop,
    dataList ,
  }));
```

Edit :

I have also tried

```
const x = () =>
      createSelector(data , prop => prop.get('text'));
```

Comment: you need to select `dataList`, not `addData`

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo in `const data = state => state.get('addData', initialState);`

`addData` should be `dataList`.